# How to prevent division by zero or replace infinite values in Theano?

Tags: python, numpy, nan, divide-by-zero, theano

I'm using a cost function in Theano which involves a regularizer term that requires me to compute this term:

```
T.sum(c / self.squared_euclidean_distances)
```

as some values of self.squared_euclidean_distances might be zero this produces Nan values. How can i work around this problem? I tried to use T.isinf but were not successful. One solution would be to remove zeros in self.squared_euclidean_distances into a small number or replace infinite numbers in T.sum(c / self.squared_euclidean_distances) to zero. I just don't know how to replace those values in Theano.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [`T.switch`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#condition). You could do for example

```
T.switch(T.eq(self.squared_euclidean_distances, 0), 0, c / self.squared_euclidean_distances)
```

(Or, upstream, you make sure that you never compare a vector with itself using squared euclidean distance.)

Comment: I'm using your solution to find the pairwise distances of rows of a matrix without loops so i can't use the upstream solution easily I guess.

Comment: There was a rejected edit on this that should have been approved, changing `==` to `T.eq`. I will do this change myself, because I don't know how to reapprove a falsely rejected edit.